# SQL select statement with where clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql

how would i write this sql statement without a hard coded value?

```
resultSet = statement
    .executeQuery("select * from myDatabase.myTable where name = 'john'");
// this works
```

rather have something like:

```
String name = "john"; 
resultSet = statement
    .executeQuery("select * from myDatabase.myTable where name =" + name);
// Unknown column 'john' in 'where clause' at
// sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0...etc...
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Use *prepared statements*

Comment: One of the reasons why people are telling you to use *prepared statements*, is because what you're trying to do in your second example is vulnerable to a [Sql Injection Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Giwrgos_ perhaps you should open eclipse and try it... then you'll see that you are wrong..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**It is a terrible idea to construct SQL queries the way you currently do, as it opens the door to all sorts of SQL injection attacks**. To do this properly, you'll have to use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead. This will also resolve all sorts of escaping issues that you're evidently having at the moment.

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from myDatabase.myTable where name = ?");    
statement.setString(1, name);    
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Note that `prepareStatement()` is an expensive call (unless your application server uses statement caching and other similar facilities). Theoretically, it'd be best if you prepare the statement once, and then reuse it multiple times (though *not* concurrently):

```
String[] names = new String[] {"Isaac", "Hello"};
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from myDatabase.myTable where name = ?");

for (String name: names) {
    statement.setString(1, name);    
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    ...
    ...
    statement.clearParameters();
}
```

Comment: Can you expand that answer with an example

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the single quotes around your string, your code corrected:

```
String name = "john";
String sql = "select * from myDatabase.myTable where name = '" + name + "'";
// Examine the text of the query in the debugger, log it or print it out using System.out.println
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Print out / log text of the query before executing the query to see if it looks OK.

If you are going to do a lot of similar queries where only the constant changes, consider using [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: are you sure you managed to copy the code from the answer correctly? This really should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
String name = "john"; 
resultSet = statement
    .executeQuery("select * from myDatabase.myTable where name =" + "'" + name + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put quotes around the value ('john' instead of john)...

Comment: This is correct according to me. What the answer says....is : Change String name = "john";  to   String name = "'john'";     Thats all(add quotes inside the String quotes...as the answer says!)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
String name = "john"; 

resultSet = statement
      .executeQuery("select * from myDatabase.myTable where myTable.name = '" + name + "'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Put quotes around your `name` value since it's a string.

```
"select * from myDatabase.myTable where name ='" + name + "'"
```