# ResultSet.next() causes SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'NM21' to data type int

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to make a server that can accept a query from a client, find the matching record, and return relevant information. There's a lot of code here, but the most relevant part is the method `getProduct(String code)`. I included as much connection information as I could incase you'd like to look, but my test query works over this connection. My test query is:

`ResultSet a = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 10 Code, [name in english], NetSalesPrice, PriceList1 FROM [REDACTED]");`

```
class PCServer {
Connection dataConn;
public static void main(String[] args){
    new PCServer();
}
public PCServer(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataConn = DriverManager.getConnection([REDACTED]);
        System.out.println("REPORT: Connected to Database");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket([REDACTED]);
        Socket cs = null;
        while(true){
            cs = ss.accept();
            ThreadServer ts = new ThreadServer(cs, this);
            ts.start();
        }
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getProduct(String code){
    System.out.println("REPORT from PCS.getProduct(): code == "+ code);
    String query = "SELECT Code, [name in english], NetSalesPrice, PriceList1 FROM [REDACTED] WHERE Code=";
    query = query.concat(code);
    System.out.println("REPORT from PCS.getProduct(): Query: "+ query);

    String productDescription = code+":Not:Found";
    try{
        Statement s = dataConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);
        if(rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
            System.out.println("REPORT from PCS.getProduct(): rs.isBeforeFirst == true");
            rs.next(); //This is throwing com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion Failed...
            productDescription = rs.getString(1) + ":" + rs.getString(2) + ":$" + rs.getString(3);
        }
    }catch (SQLException sqle){
        System.out.println("SQL Server Exception in getProduct(String code)");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }

    return productDescription;
}
```

It seems like the exception is the result of a datatype-error or NumberFormatException when the ResultSet is either created or accessed. However, I tried casting code to an int, and the error stays even when the line `productDescription = rs.getString(1) + ":" + rs.getString(2) + ":$" + rs.getString(3);` is commented out. I am confident that the error is being thrown by `rs.next()`. Furthermore, we know that rs is not empty because we checked `rs.isBeforeFirst()`, which would return false if the ResultSet were empty.

Here is the full message

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'NM21' to data type int.
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4853)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1781)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1034)
   at PCServer.getProduct(PCServer.java:83)
   at PCServer$ThreadServer.run(PCServer.java:128)
```

I know that question looks similar to others. There are many other posts about this error, but none of them are being thrown by `ResultSet.next()`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, and it turned out to be a pretty stupid mistake. But https://xkcd.com/979/ has taught me not to abandon my questions.

My Query needed single quotes around code. so it should be:

`statement.executeQuery("SELECT Code, [name in english], NetSalesPrice, PriceList1 FROM ERPLY_ITEMS WHERE Code='"+code+"'")` Rather than:

`statement.executeQuery("SELECT Code, [name in english], NetSalesPrice, PriceList1 FROM ERPLY_ITEMS WHERE Code="+code)`

I'd been overlooking that for an embarrassing amount of time. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565127/7395557) to a question about procedurally generated queries with a WHERE clause, concatenation is a pretty vulnerable method of query generation. Instead, Isaac recommends using [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to generate queries programmatically.

I hope this will help someone eventually.

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate values into a query at all, you should use a prepared statement with parameter placeholders. Your current code (and your solution) is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I saw that in another question, it's why I included the last paragraph. I was just trying to explain the issue I was having. But I have since changed my program to make use of prepared statements, rather than concatenation.