# Java mysql - How to Update database from textbox

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me what is wrong to my query.
I have textbox to update the occupantname but it doesn't work, Only Status works.

```
String gOccupied = "Occupied" ;
String query = "UPDATE `rooms` SET `occupantname` = '"+txtFirstNames.getText()+"' , `status`='"+gOccupied+"' WHERE roomnumber = " +CBRoomNumber.getSelectedItem();

executeSQlquery(query,""+" Updated");
```

Comment: do you get any error? if it is then please update above.

Comment: i don't have any error. It's just only status is updating, But occupantname doesn't update

Comment: Hmm, then i doubt that the value of "txtFirstNames.getText()" not getting changed , please debug it, you could find why it it is happening.

Comment: I can't really find the error

Comment: You could use System.out.println(txtFirstNames.getText()); before the query string , and check the console whether the value is getting changed or not.

Comment: Show the code in `executeSQlquery` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please tell me what is wrong to my query. i have textbox
>   to update the occupantname but it doesn't work, Only Status works.

Don't use direct MySql SQL with these special characters **`**

> String query = "UPDATE `rooms` SET `occupantname` =
>   '"+txtFirstNames.getText()+"' , `status`='"+gOccupied+"' WHERE
>   roomnumber = " +CBRoomNumber.getSelectedItem();
>   Blockquote

Instated Use below SQL

> String query = "UPDATE rooms SET occupantname = ? , status= ? WHERE roomnumber = ?";

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    private static PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;
    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String gOccupied = "Occupied";
        String occupantname = txtFirstNames.getText();
        String query = "UPDATE rooms SET occupantname = ? , status= ? WHERE roomnumber = ?";
        try {
            executeSQlquery(query, occupantname, gOccupied, "Updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void executeSQlquery(String query, String occupantname, String gOccupied, String status) throws SQLException {
        try {
            // create a java mysql database connection
            String myDriver = "org.mysql.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "username", "password");
            preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, occupantname);
            preparedStmt.setString(2, gOccupied);
            preparedStmt.setInt(3, 101);

            // execute the java preparedstatement
            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            if (preparedStmt != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It is generally a terrible idea to construct SQL queries the way you currently do, as it opens the door to all sorts of SQL injection attacks. To do this properly, you'll have to use Prepared Statements instead. This will also resolve all sorts of escaping issues that you're evidently having at the moment.

[SQL select statement with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565097/sql-select-statement-with-where-clause)